# Worksheet change ambiguous name solution?

Tags: vba, excel

I know that a single sheet can't have two independent subs named worksheet change. So I removed it.

I can't figure out the modification I require to make this code run though. Would love some help.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)


If Target.Row = 10 And Target.Column = 121 And Target.Count = 1 Then

Set Target = Range("range1")

If Target <> "Calculate" Then Exit Sub

Select Case Target.Value
Case "Calculate"
    macro1

End Select
End If


ElseIf Target.Row = 10 And Target.Column = 123 And Target.Count = 1 Then

Set Target = Range("range2")

If Target <> "Calculate" Then Exit Sub

Select Case Target.Value
Case "Calculate"
   macro2

End Select

End If

End If



End Sub
```

Comment: If `macro1` or `macro2` change **anything** on the worksheet, disable events temporarily. Do **not** reassign Target.

Comment: What is your code supposed to do, and what is it doing?

Comment: Does the code run, but not work? Does it throw an error? What's the issue?

Comment: Jeeped: Macro 1 and macro 2 respond to a cell change which results in a factor being applied to some numbers. The new numbers are copied into a range.  When would I disabled events? at the top of the macro? at its current condition the error it throws is else without if

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work for you.  As a note, never try to reassign the `Target` argument:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim rngCheck1 As Range
    Dim rngCheck2 As Range

    Set rngCheck1 = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("DQ10")) 'Row 10, Column 121
    Set rngCheck2 = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("DS10")) 'Row 10, Column 123

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    On Error GoTo CleanExit

    If Not rngCheck1 Is Nothing Then
        If Trim(LCase(rngCheck1.Value)) = "calculate" Then Call macro1
    End If

    If Not rngCheck2 Is Nothing Then
        If Trim(LCase(rngCheck2.Value)) = "calculate" Then Call macro2
    End If

CleanExit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Would an `ElseIf` be appropriate here so that `rngCheck2` is not checked if `rngCheck1` is true?

Comment: @Jeeped It's certainly possible that would be a more preferable solution.  The title of the post is about an ambiguous name which I interpreted as the OP wanting to have two simultaneous worksheet_change events which is why I wrote it this way.  Doing the ElseIf would work just fine though

Comment: Actually, I suppose both could be true as there is no check to see if Target is a single cell.